# Setup SSL on AWS EC2 windows instance running xampp

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2

Need help installing SSL on XAMPP windows server on AWS. I have configured SSL on the Xampp server localhost. I can access the the https when I remote(RDP) into the server, but cannot access from the outside world. Certificate is installed and configured on XAMPP apache. When I use the domain signed, on remote Xampp, it works but doesn't outside there server.

Comment: Can any one help please?

Comment: What error do you see when you try to connect?  Have you configured the firewall on the security group?

Comment: @AnonCoward I have sir. That is if you mean opening the port for HTTPS.